# Using Ruby on Rails to write to an Excel spreadsheet AND include html markup in the text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel

I have a Ruby on Rails web application in which the user clicks on a link which produces a spreadsheet.

It was easy enough to do this.  What I haven't been able to do is get it to write text in the cells formatted according to html tags.

```
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new

sheet = book.create_worksheet :name => "My worksheet"

sheet[0,0] = "<strong style="color:red">I want this to appear as red</strong>"
```

And I get it that you can use the Spreadsheet:Format.new object to set the format for a cell or a row - but in this case I won't know this ahead of time; I need for the spreadsheet to automatically interpret html tags as the text is sucked in from a database.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, whether these HTML tags can directly be converted to styles in excel sheets. I faced a few problems when dealing with rails and microsoft office outputs.

Check out this blog, this might help you. http://axlsx.blog.randym.net/2011/12/axlsx-making-excel-reports-with-ruby-on.html

so maybe, you can create a function.. Parse your styling tags, and then accordingly convert them to the excel supported params mentioned in the blog

Comment: I have a file in Rails Application with xlsx.axlsx extension to genearte excel file. In that file I have used , note = (notes.content).html_safe . But, data shows with html tags , like  <table><tr><td>Subject</td></tr></table>.How can I avoid the tags